# xcode 6 - swift - passing a string through popover segue

Tags: swift, webview, segue, popover

My project has two view controllers. The initial view controller has three buttons (viewController1). The second view controller has a webview (viewController2). I set up a present as popover segue from the viewController1 to viewController2. I would like each button to open a specific webpage in the webview when the segue occurs (when I tap one button, the webview slides up with one website. If I tap a different button, the webview slides up with a different predetermined website.)

How do I pass the predetermined website to viewController2?

my code so far:

```
 // viewController1
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if (segue.identifier == "webViewPopover") {
         let webviewVC:WebviewViewController = segue.destinationViewController as WebviewViewController
         webviewVC.receivedURL = "http://www.apple.com" //test string
        }
    }


// viewController2
var receivedURL:String!

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = NSURL (string: receivedURL)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the way you did it.

If you are asking, how can I derive different strings from different buttons, the easiest way is to have different handlers that set a local variable, which is then proxied to the next VC as you have done.  That is the most straight forward way.

A more advanced technique that I have used (probably too much for now), is to wrap a closure in an object, pass that as the sender, and have an agnostic prepareForSegue check the sender and dispatch the method.  For your needs though, go with Apple's API - what you are doing, just feed it a local string variable cached in the button click.